# Connection to Mariadb in a C# application

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mariadb

I am new to C#. I am trying to make a connection to my On-Premise MariaDb Database using a simple Windows Forms application. Where my connection is getting established successfully but later it was getting closed by my remote host forcibly. I am attaching my code. Can you guys check this code and help me what is the missing piece. Thanks in advance.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            connectionString = @"Data Source=xxx.xxx.x.xx,xxxx;Initial Catalog=dataBaseName;User ID=UID;Password=Password";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Open !");
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully
> established with the server, but then an error occurred during the
> pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing
> connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)'

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient` is for SQL Server which is something altogether different from MySQL and MariaDB

Comment: instead of `System.Data.sqlClient` what works for `MariaDB` @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain

Comment: You can look on nuget for an appropriate MySQL connector. Look for *MySQL Connector/Net`.  The api is very similar to the built in SQL Server connector.

Comment: thanks @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain. I found one I used `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` for that and it worked.

Comment: thanks @O.Jones. I found one.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to MariaDB from .NET, first add the Nuget Package `MySqlConnector` to your project

or

add the following package reference to your `*.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="MySqlConnector" Version="2.3.5" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Add the import

```
using MySqlConnector;
```

Then you can use the following method to connect to a MariaDB instance:

```
private static void Connect(string server, string dbName, string userName, string password)
{
    string connectionString = $"Server={server};Database={dbName};User={userName};Password={password};";
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection succeeded.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Connection error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```cs
string server = "127.0.0.1";
string dbName = "test";
string userName = "root";
string password = "sa";

Connect(server, dbName, userName, password);
```